# Show sales per employee (staff) and year in sakila db?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm kind of stuck on an excercise concerning the [sakila db](https://database.guide/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/sakila_full_database_schema_diagram.png).
I want to show sales per employee (staff) and year in mySQL and I'm failing at using the staff_id's correctly.

This is all I have so far:

```
SELECT  staff_id,payment_id
FROM staff s
LEFT JOIN payment p USING (staff_id)
```

Can anyone explain to me how to use the staff_id in both staff and payment to display sales per employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and aggregate function `sum` as follows:

```
SELECT staff_id, sum(amount) as sales_per_staff 
FROM staff s LEFT JOIN payment p USING (staff_id)
Where ... -- use condition according to your requirement
Group by staff_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Could you explain how you would display the sales per year? If I just add the payment_date into SELECT and declare it as YEAR, that wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: You need to convert your paymemtdate to year and use it in select and group by clause